# Why am I missing a file from the library `stdlib_list`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed a library named `stdlib_list`
When I execute the following code, I get an error message.

```
import importlib
from stdlib_list import stdlib_list
x = iter(stdlib_list())
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/common_function_names.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = iter(stdlib_list())
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\stdlib_list\base.py", line 44, in stdlib_list
    with open(module_list_file) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Sam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\stdlib_list\\lists\\3.8.txt'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is the file missing?

```
C:\Users\Sam>C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install stdlib_list --user

Requirement already satisfied: stdlib_list in c:\users\sam\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (0.5.0)
```

## Build:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      Time of this report: 10/25/2019, 07:22:01
             Machine name: DESKTOP-U5M46TJ
               Machine Id: {403D9006-3BF1-4C4B-AAF5-2AD795E00738}
         Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
             System Model: System Product Name
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 10/31/12 20:41:07 Ver: 36.02 (type: BIOS)
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
                   Memory: 4096MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 4064MB RAM
                Page File: 12606MB used, 3744MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\Windows
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 144 DPI (150 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
                 Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
 DirectX Database Version: Unknown
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0387 64bit Unicode

------------------
IDE Information
------------------
PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-191.7479.30, built on May 29, 2019
JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.60 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

------------------
Python Information
------------------
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
print(sys.hexversion)

3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
50856176
```

Comment: The `stdlib_list` module contains lists of the standard modules that were included with various versions of Python.  It apparently has no list for Python 3.8 yet.  You could pass an explicit older version number to `stdlib_list()`  - `stdlib_list('3.6')` perhaps - and get the list for that version, although that might not actually be of any use to you.

Answer (score 1):

All credit for this answer goes to [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper)

The `stdlib_list` module automatically looks-up the version of python currently is use, and attempts to open a file a corresponding to it. There is no file for Python 3.8 yet. The solution is to pass an older version number to `stdlib_list()`, such as `stdlib_list('3.6')`, and get the list for that version.

Comment: Hi, I come from the future, in 2023 I just had the issue that aioify has the same problem, file 3.10.txt was not found by stdlib_list, I am using poetry and python 3.10 so I am not sure how to solve this for me. Anyway passed by to give you a thumbs up since this was useful.